# problem in code coverage

Tags: code-coverage

I am have 66% percent for test class

**class:**

```
public with sharing class empdepExtensionNew
{

    public Contact[] Availabledeps {get;set;}
    public dep__c[] shoppingCart{get; set;}
    //public dep__c[] total{get; set;}
    public emp__c theemp {get; set;}
    public String tonSelect{get; set;}
    public String toUnselect{get; set;}
    public String searchString{get; set;}
    //public String value{get; set;}
    public Boolean AccountRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean ContactRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean LeadRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean OpportunityRT{get; set;}
    public String UserID {get; set;}

    private dep__c[] forDeletion = new dep__c[]{};
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    //Constructor

    public empdepExtensionNew (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller= controller;
        if(controller.getrecord() == null)
        system.debug(controller.getrecord().id);

        //UserID = UserInfo.getname(); 

        //emping Custom Setting object for Recordtypes in emp object

        Record_Type_Name__c Accrt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('AccRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Conrt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('ConRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Leart = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('LeaRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Opprt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('OppRecordTypeID');

        //Condition to check the record type for emp object 

        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Accrt.Record_Type__c){
            AccountRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Conrt.Record_Type__c){
            ContactRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Leart.Record_Type__c){
            LeadRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Opprt.Record_Type__c){
            OpportunityRT = TRUE;
        }

      { 
            //String value = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

            //total =[Select id,name,empId__c,Contact_Id__c,emp_Date__c,dep__c.Contact_Id__r.Name from dep__c ];
            shoppingCart = [Select id,name,empId__c,Contact_Id__c,emp_Date__c,dep__c.Contact_Id__r.Name from dep__c where id =: tonSelect]; 

       }
       updateAvailableList();
     }

    public void updateAvailableList() 
    {

        UserID = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        String qString =  'select id, Name, Title, Contact.MailingCity,Contact.MailingState,Contact.Account.Name from Contact  where User_Id__c not in (select ID from User where id =: UserID )' ;
        system.debug(qString);

        if(searchString!=null)

        {          
            qString+= ' and ( Contact.Name like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Contact.RACFID__c like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Contact.Officer_Code__c like \'%' + searchString + '%\') ';                       
        }

       Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
       if(tonSelect!=null)
        for(dep__c d : shoppingCart){
            selectedEntries.add(d.Contact_Id__c);
        }

        if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
            String tempFilter = ' and id not in (';
            for(id i : selectedEntries){
                tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
            }
            String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
            extraFilter+= ')';

            qString+= extraFilter;
        } 

        qString+= ' order by Name';
        qString+= ' limit 12';
        system.debug('qString:' +qString );               
        Availabledeps = database.query(qString);
        system.debug(Availabledeps);

    } 

    public void addToShoppingCart()

    // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a dep

    { 
      for(Contact part : Availabledeps)
       {
        if((String)part.id==tonSelect)
            {

                shoppingCart.add(new dep__c (Contact_Id__c =part.id));
                system.debug(shoppingCart);
                system.debug(shoppingCart.size());
                break;

            }          

        }
         updateAvailableList();

    }  

      public PageReference removeFromShoppingCart(){

        // This function runs when a user hits "remove" on "Selected dep" section

        Integer count = 0;

        for(dep__c del : shoppingCart){
            if((String)del.Contact_Id__c==toUnselect){

                if(del.Id!=null)
                    forDeletion.add(del);

                shoppingCart.remove(count);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }

        updateAvailableList();

        return null;
    }

     // This function runs when user hits save button

     public PageReference onSave(){

        try{

            PageReference pageRef = controller.save();
            system.debug(controller.getrecord().id);

                if(shoppingCart.size()>0) 

                  for (dep__c partmember : shoppingCart ){
                     partmember.empId__c=controller.getrecord().id;
                     System.debug(partmember.empId__c);
                  }

                  System.debug('size' +shoppingCart.size());
                  insert(shoppingCart);
                }


            catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }  
           System.debug('completed');

        // After save return the user to the emp
       return new PageReference('/' + controller.getrecord().id);  
    }     
}
```

**test class:**

```
@istest(seealldata=true)
Public class Test_empdepExtensionNew
{
Public static testmethod void empdepExtensionNew_test()
{
    Record_Type_Name__c opprt =[select  ID,name,Record_Type__c from Record_Type_Name__c where name ='OppRecordTypeID']; 
    PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/empCustomNew?id='+opprt.Id);
    nextpage.setredirect(true);
    emp__c  c = new emp__c(Subject__c = 'TestdepExtension',emp_Type__c = 'BD Monthly Update',emp_Date__c = system.today(),
    Status__c = 'DONE',OpportunityId__c='006q0000004QWR7',RecordtypeId=opprt.Record_Type__c);
    insert c;
    empdepExtensionNew e = new  empdepExtensionNew(new ApexPages.StandardController(c));
    contact con = new contact(LastName='test',Contact_Type__c='Business contact',AccountId='001q000000BDufL');
    insert con;
        e.updateAvailableList();
        e.addToShoppingCart();
        e.removeFromShoppingCart();
        e.onSave(); 
        dep__c p1 = new dep__c(empId__c=c.id,Contact_Id__c='003q000000CrgjD');
        dep__c p2 = new dep__c(empId__c=c.id,Contact_Id__c='003q000000CvPct');
        List<dep__c> part = new List<dep__c>();
        part.add(p1);
        part.add(p2);
        insert part; 
        //System.assertEquals(3, [select count() from dep__c where empId__c=:c.id]);
    }    
}
```

kindly elp me out to get more coverage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve your code coverage then you have to add below line in your code after checking your custom setting value.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType', 'Your cusom setting value here');
```